# How to force newpage on tabularx

Tags: page-breaking, tabularx

I wanted to make a table, but needed to force a couple of rows go to the next page. However, I got a strange error.

How can I force a `newpage` using `tabularx`?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc}
abc & abc \\
abc & abc \\
\newpage
abc & abc \\
abc & abc \\
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can't split `tabularx` across pages.

Comment: See the [`ltxtable` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/ltxtable).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That is not possible with default `tabularx`. Use package `ltablex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc}
        abc & abc \\
        abc & abc \\
        \pagebreak
        abc & abc \\
        abc & abc \\
    \end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```